# How to minimize a QDialog?

Tags: c++, qt

While I understand that `QDialog` is not meant for minimum state, Is it possible to minimize a `QDialog` programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[QWidget::setWindowState()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setWindowState) will let you minimize/maximize etc programatically

Comment: Well, I accept your answer but it does not work on my Ubuntu 10.04 :(.